# Powershell | Only run if it the First Thursday of the Month

Tags: powershell

Not sure where to start at all.  Very stuck.  Tried a few things similar to [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576860/powershell-getting-the-nth-day-of-the-month)

The idea is that IF it is the First Thursday of the Month then proceed Else do something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
$d = Get-Date # Get Current Date
# Check if today is Thursday and the day number is less than 8
if ($d.DayOfWeek -eq 'Thursday' -and $d.Day -lt 8) {
    "First Thursday"
}
else { 
    "Not First Thursday"
}
```

---

You could make this more dynamic by creating a function so that you can enter any date and any day of week.

```
function Check-FirstDay {
    param([datetime]$Date,[DayOfWeek]$DayOfWeek)

    if ($Date.DayOfWeek -eq $DayOfWeek -and $Date.Day -lt 8) {
        "It is first $DayOfWeek"
    }
    else {
        "It is not first $DayOfWeek"
    }
 }
```

**Examples Using the Function:**

```
# Example when it is not first Tuesday
$d = Get-Date
$d
Check-FirstDay -Date $d -DayOfWeek Tuesday

# Output
Tuesday, April 21, 2020 11:32:45 AM
It is not first Tuesday

# Example when it is first Thursday
$d = (Get-Date).AddDays(16)
$d
Check-FirstDay -Date $d -DayOfWeek Thursday

# Output
Thursday, May 7, 2020 11:35:34 AM
It is first Thursday
```

**Testing with Thursday October 1, 2020:**

```
$d = Get-Date -Month 10 -Year 2020 -Day 1
Check-FirstDay -Date $d -DayOfWeek Thursday

# Output
It is first Thursday
```

Comment: for $d.Day -lt 8, is this just checking how many days in the month have passed? Since first Thursday will be  less than eight days? Concern would be what if Thursday is the first day of the month (October) would 8 use the first or second Thursday

Comment: `-lt` is less than. `-le` is less than equal to. `Day` specifies the day number of the date.

Comment: In October, Day 1 is first Thursday in this example.

Comment: Best way to test this ?

Comment: I added an example at the end of the post of how to test October 1

Comment: Thank you very much